# Shiny object not found (dataset not loaded)

Tags: r, object, shiny

I have a problem working with shiny. Eveything was going well, and now, I have this "ERROR: object 'pwhour' not found" problem.

Here my server code:

```
    setwd("~mypath")
    ###############################################################

    #####load dataset##############################################
    pwhour<-read.csv("pwhour.csv",sep=',',header=TRUE)
    names(pwhour)[names(pwhour)=="X"] <- "date"
    pwhour$date<-as.POSIXct(pwhour$date,format="%y-%m-%d %H")
    pwhour$date2<-as.POSIXct(pwhour$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H")

    #####
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {


      # Widget date
      output$value <- renderPrint({ input$dates })


      #Plot hour
      output$HourPlot <- renderPlot({

        ggplot()+geom_line(data = pwhour, aes(x = date, y = y_pred, color =       "blue"))  +
          geom_line(data = pwhour, aes(x = date, y = powerall, color =  "red")) +xlab('Date') +
      ylab('Power consumption')+scale_x_datetime(limits=c(as.POSIXct(input$dates[1]),as.POSIXct(input$dates[2])))
      })
      })
```

I have already tried to put my read csv in reactive after the shinyserver call, but it didn't helped. My local environment is empty.Before restarting my computer, it was working well.
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `mypath` a real folder? If so, try `setwd('~/mypath')`

Comment: Thank you! `mypath` is a path to a folder `'~/Myfolder/Mysubfolder/Mysubsubfolder'`. I have tried to change " by ' , but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is you put the file in the app folder?

Comment: What if you put the data loading within the server function

Comment: I've already tried, but I have the same error.

Comment: You did try it with with a Slash ('/')? If you use `"` or `'` does not change anything...

Comment: do you have an error stating `Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection` ?

Comment: Yes I have tried with '/' but doesn't change anything...And I don't have an error in file error, sorry....